# Filter index hits by node ids in Neo4j

Tags: filter, indexing, neo4j, dataset

I have a set of node id's (Set< Long >) and want to restrict or filter the results of an query to only the nodes in this set. Is there a performant way to do this?

```
 Set<Node> query(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb, final Set<Long> nodeSet) {
    final Index<Node> searchIndex = graphdb.index().forNodes("search");
    final IndexHits<Node> hits = searchIndex.query(new QueryContext("value*"));
    // what now to return only index hits that are in the given Set of Node's?
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fastest solution I found was directly using lucenes [IndexSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) on the index created by neo4j and use an custom [Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html) to restrict the search to specific nodes.

Just open the neo4j index folder "{neo4j-database-folder}/index/lucene/node/{index-name}" with the lucene [IndexReader](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html). Make sure to use not add a lucene dependency to your project in another version than the one neo4j uses, which currently is lucene 3.6.2!

here's my lucene [Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html) implementation that filters all query results by the given Set of document id's. (Lucene Document id's (Integer) ARE NOT Neo4j Node id's (Long)!)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.search.DocIdSet;
import org.apache.lucene.search.DocIdSetIterator;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Filter;

public class DocIdFilter extends Filter {

    public class FilteredDocIdSetIterator extends DocIdSetIterator {

        private final PriorityQueue<Integer> filterQueue;

        private int docId;

        public FilteredDocIdSetIterator(final Set<Integer> filterSet) {
            this(new PriorityQueue<Integer>(filterSet));
        }

        public FilteredDocIdSetIterator(final PriorityQueue<Integer> filterQueue) {
            this.filterQueue = filterQueue;
        }
        @Override
        public int docID() {
            return this.docId;
        }

        @Override
        public int nextDoc() throws IOException {
            if (this.filterQueue.isEmpty()) {
                this.docId = NO_MORE_DOCS;
            } else {
                this.docId = this.filterQueue.poll();
            }
            return this.docId;
        }

        @Override
        public int advance(final int target) throws IOException {
            while ((this.docId = this.nextDoc()) < target)
                ;
            return this.docId;
        }

    }

    private final PriorityQueue<Integer> filterQueue;

    public DocIdFilter(final Set<Integer> filterSet) {
        super();
        this.filterQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(filterSet);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -865683019349988312L;

    @Override
    public DocIdSet getDocIdSet(final IndexReader reader) throws IOException {
        return new DocIdSet() {
            @Override
            public DocIdSetIterator iterator() throws IOException {
                return new FilteredDocIdSetIterator(DocIdFilter.this.filterQueue);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

To map the set of neo4j node id's (the query result should be filtered with) to the correct lucene document id's i created an inmemory [bidirectional map](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html):

```java
public static HashBiMap<Integer, Long> generateDocIdToNodeIdMap(final IndexReader indexReader)
    throws LuceneIndexException {
    final HashBiMap<Integer, Long> result = HashBiMap.create(indexReader.numDocs());
    for (int i = 0; i < indexReader.maxDoc(); i++) {
    if (indexReader.isDeleted(i)) {
        continue;
    }
    final Document doc;
    try {
        doc = indexReader.document(i, new FieldSelector() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5853247619312916012L;
            @Override
            public FieldSelectorResult accept(final String fieldName) {
                    if ("_id_".equals(fieldName)) {
                        return FieldSelectorResult.LOAD_AND_BREAK;
                    } else {
                        return FieldSelectorResult.NO_LOAD;
                    }
                }
            };
        );
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new LuceneIndexException(indexReader.directory(), "could not read document with ID: '" + i
            + "' from index.", e);
    }
    final Long nodeId;
    try {
        nodeId = Long.valueOf(doc.get("_id_"));
    } catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new LuceneIndexException(indexReader.directory(),
            "could not parse node ID value from document ID: '" + i + "'", e);
    }
    result.put(i, nodeId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm using the [Google Guava Library](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) that provides an bidirectional map and the initialization of collections with an specific size.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be faster the other way round? If you get the nodes from your set and compare the property to the value you are looking for?

```
for (Iterator it=nodeSet.iterator();it.hasNext();) {
   Node n=db.getNodeById(it.next());
   if (!n.getProperty("value","").equals("foo")) it.remove();
}
```

or for your suggestion

```
 Set<Node> query(final GraphDatabaseService graphDb, final Set<Long> nodeSet) {
    final Index<Node> searchIndex = graphdb.index().forNodes("search");
    final IndexHits<Node> hits = searchIndex.query(new QueryContext("value*"));
    Set<Node> result=new HashSet<>();
    for (Node n : hits) {
       if (nodeSet.contains(n.getId())) result.add(n);
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your answer! The problem is that i don't know the properties the given nodeSet was created with. This could also be randomly picked by the user. I will try the approach from your suggestion, but that could get slow with millions of nodes right?